# Edit specific product

Tags: php

On my website i have a page where you can add, edit and delete products. On every product there are buttons that are "edit" and "delete", but what i want is if you click the edit or delete button that it will edit or delete that specific one you click on.

The products are shown in a foreach: (things are Dutch btw, don't think it would matter)

```
            $show = new Docent();
            $opties = $show->toonOpties();

            foreach ($opties as $optie){
                echo "<div class='optieContainer'>";
                echo "Type: " . $optie["optieType"] . "<br>" . "Naam: " . $optie["optieNaam"] . "<br>" . "Beschrijving: " . $optie["optieBeschrijving"] . '<br><br><br>';
                echo "<div class='optieKnoppen'><button class='-'>Aanpassen</button> ";
                echo "<button class='-'>Verwijderen</button></div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
```

So if you click edit, you should go to the edit page with the product info autofilled in the form or go to a specific edit page that is only for the product you want to edit. And if you click delete it will delete the product you clicked delete on. 
But how can i do this? If there are questions please let me know.

Comment: The product must have some kind of identifier (usually "id" integer column in database). You pass that id to the edit page as an argument (usually through `$_GET`) and the page loads the product info from database by that id.

Comment: You can use value button for example 'Aanpassen' : `value='Aanpassen-$id'`  and use it for update just that value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the ID(Or any unique identifier) with the button click. You have not yet added anything besides a button, but you could make it like this:

```
echo "<a href='edit.php?id=".$optie->id."'>Aanpassen</a>"
```

The `edit.php` in href being the page you want to go to.

Then in `edit.php`, you can use:`$_GET['id']` and it will return the `$optie->id` from the previous page. Then use this parameter in the query to get the information to autofill the form.

**NOTE: Make sure its secure. Taking my specific example, you would be vulnerable to injection, since people can change the ** `$_GET['id']` ** to anything they want. You need to only accept legit values and protect against SQL Injection, but this is another thing you have to worry about that's not specific to this question.**